# neo4j stop traversal on condition (cypher)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm just starting out so pardon me if this is a stupid question but I was wondering how to stop traversal of a tree on a node property value.

For instance. If you have a tree type graph with nodes and subnodes. All nodes have a property of `published` which is either  `1` or `0`. I would like to traverse the tree not including any node with a `published:0` (nor it's children even if they have a `published:1`)

So far (with n being the root node) `n-[:HAS_CHILD_CONTENT*]->m WHERE m.published=1 return m;` will obviously simply return all published nodes ignoring the fact that some nodes have an unpublished parent

Can anyone help me sort this out? Thanks in advancce.

PS: 
I'm using `Neo4j - Graph Database Kernel 2.0.0-M02` through the webapp cypher shell on `ubuntu 12.04 LTS`

Comment: Why not just add `AND n.published = 1`?

Comment: @ean5533 that doesn't work. it will still select subnodes that are published even though one of the parent nodes is unpublished

Comment: Ah, you added a `*` to your query that wasn't there before.

Comment: @ean5533 yeah sorry about that. I realized later only that I forgot to put that in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can examine the path, like

```
match p=root-[:PARENT*..]-file 
   where root.name='a' and all(x in nodes(p) WHERE x.published = true) 
return p;
```

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/preview/query-function.html#functions-all

See http://bit.ly/12ARbL5 for an example.

Comment: That's perfect!! Thank you very much! I missed that all was used in that manner from documentation.
Do you know what incidence `all` has on query performance? And/or if there are ways of optimizing performance?

Comment: It is probably not the fastest, as it Cypher does not yet pull these cross path expressions into the pattern matcher. If the performance doesn't meet your needs, check out the Java core API (`node.getRelationships` and `node.getProperty`) or the traversal API (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorial-traversal.html) to shortcut the traversal when you encounter an unpublished parent.